# Download data from Google Chrome Sync before deleting

Tags: google-chrome, google-sync, google-accounts

I would like to clear the data synced by Chrome to my google account: history, open tab, extensions, auto-filled form fields,...

But, before, I would also like to download all the data on my account.

I do not find this service on google takeout, and I can only "reset synchronisation" on this page: https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync

Answer (score -1):

To get the data and only that data , 
you'd have to create a new blank Chrome profile , 
login to Chrome and wait for all the synced data to 
download. Then close Chrome and make a backup copy/archive 
of the profile folder.
And remember the password of the logged in Windows user.

Doublecheck whether you have anything in passwords.google.com .

Comment: Indeed, it could be possible to get datas from the profile, but I would like them in a more formatted way.